# set Datagirdviewcombobox column value in Vb.net

Tags: datagridviewcombobox

I have datagrid with two datagridviewcombo column, one column is dynamic fill and one has fixed hardcoded values. 
The problem is I can't set the value of dynamic GridViewComboBox, when I try to set it generates continues errors.

> System.FormateException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell Value is not valid.

My code to load the grid is

> ```
>    Dim dt As DataTable
>     dt = GetDataTable("Select valuecol,displayCol From mytable")  'GetDataTable gives me datatable
>     cmbAntibiotics.DataSource = dt
>     cmbAntibiotics.DisplayMember = "Antibiotics"
>     cmbAntibiotics.ValueMember = "AntibioticsID"
> ```

```
    Dim Index As Integer

    Dim dgr As DataGridViewRow
    For Each dr As DataRow In dtFromDB.Rows 'This datatable is filled with database
        Index = dtFromDB.Rows.Count - 1
        GRDAntimicrobials.Rows.Add()
        GRDAntimicrobials.Rows(Index).Cells("cmbAntibiotics").Value = dr("AntibioticsID").ToString   'At this point it shows value (1,2,3) rather then showing its display members
        GRDAntimicrobials.Rows(Index).Cells("AntibioticsStatus").Value = dr("AntibioticsStatus").ToString
    Next
```

Pls help with me

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to assign the value to whatever there is on the cell rather than instantiate the object that resides in the cell and then assign its value.  I would try something like this:

```
Dim vComboBoxColumn As DropDownList = DirectCast(GRDAntimicrobials.Rows(index).Cells("cmbAntibiotics"))
vComboBoxColumn.Value = dr("AntibioticsStatus").ToString
```